# users are not grouped by units using group by

Tags: postgresql

I work with postgres as database

I want to display employe by unit

I try with this query  but as a result  employees are not grouped by units

```
select employee_lang.fullname_emp_lang,unit_lang.name_unit_lang

from employee employee,employee_lang employee_lang,unit unit,unit_lang unit_lang
where  employee.id_employe= employee_lang.id_employe
and employee_lang.lang_emp_lang='ar'
and employee.id_unit= unit.id_unit
and unit.id_unit= unit_lang.id_unit
and unit_lang.lang_unit_lang='ar'
group by employee_lang.fullname_emp_lang,unit_lang.name_unit_lang
```

for example I want to have this kind of result

```
alen     dep1
franc    dep1
med      dep1
juk      dep2
sizar    dep2
```

I try also juste to use

**group by unit_lang.name_unit_lang**

meaning

```
 select employee_lang.fullname_emp_lang,unit_lang.name_unit_lang

    from employee employee,employee_lang employee_lang,unit unit,unit_lang unit_lang
    where  employee.id_employe= employee_lang.id_employe
    and employee_lang.lang_emp_lang='ar'
    and employee.id_unit= unit.id_unit
    and unit.id_unit= unit_lang.id_unit
    and unit_lang.lang_unit_lang='ar'
    group by unit_lang.name_unit_lang
```

I have this error :

```
ERROR: column "employee_lang.fullname_emp_lang" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are after order, not grouping:

```
select employee_lang.fullname_emp_lang,unit_lang.name_unit_lang    
from employee employee,employee_lang employee_lang,unit unit,unit_lang unit_lang
where  employee.id_employe= employee_lang.id_employe
and employee_lang.lang_emp_lang='ar'
and employee.id_unit= unit.id_unit
and unit.id_unit= unit_lang.id_unit
and unit_lang.lang_unit_lang='ar'
order by unit_lang.name_unit_lang
```